# Gradle: Distributing Executable, Obfuscated Jar File

Tags: gradle, jar, proguard

I'm trying to use gradle with proguard to obfuscate the code then generate a zip file to distribute.  I'd like to use the [distribution plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html), but it always includes the jar that is generated by the jar task.  Is there some way to force the distribution plugin to omit the original (non-obfuscated) jar and only include the obfuscated jar?  I can easily add the obfuscated jar in addition to the original, but I want to distribute the obfuscated jar **instead** of the original so the generated execution scripts run against the obfuscated version.

Here's my abridged build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.3.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

task obfuscate(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    configuration 'proguard.txt'

    injars "build/libs/${rootProject.name}.jar"
    outjars "build/libs/${rootProject.name}-release.jar"
}

jar.finalizedBy(project.tasks.obfuscate)

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from(obfuscate) {
                into "lib"
            }
            from(jar) {
                exclude "*.jar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried a number of things in the distributions block to try to exclude the original jar, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't the best solution, but I was able to work around the issue by renaming the jars at the end of the obfuscation step.  Now, I name the original jar something like `<JAR_NAME>-original.jar` and I give the obfuscated jar the original jar's name.  I still wish there was a better way to do it, but this seems to work.

Here is the updated, abridged `build.gradle` file:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.3.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

def jarNameWithoutExtension = jar.archiveName.with { it.take(it.lastIndexOf(".")) }
def obfuscatedJarName = "${jarNameWithoutExtension}-release.jar"
def jarFileLocation = jar.archivePath.parent
def obfuscatedFilePath = Paths.get(jarFileLocation, obfuscatedJarName)

task obfuscate(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    configuration 'proguard.txt'

    injars jar.archivePath
    outjars obfuscatedFilePath.toString()

    // Rename the original and obfuscated jars.  We want the obfuscated jar to
    // have the original jar's name so it will get included in the distributable
    // package (generated by installDist / distZip / distTar / assembleDist).
    doLast {
        jar.archivePath.renameTo(Paths.get(jarFileLocation, "$jarNameWithoutExtension-original.jar").toFile())

        obfuscatedFilePath.toFile().renameTo(jar.archivePath)
    }
}

jar.finalizedBy(project.tasks.obfuscate)
```